# Auto size image to page size in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, cc-2014

I've got an InDesign document with 100 A4 pages.

I've got 100 assets (a mixture of .jpg and .pdf files) and I want to place 1 per page. If an image is not the proportion of the A4 page I would like to get it as big as it can be on the page before it hits into the margin. Ex. if it's a portrait image it should be as large as it can be before hits the top/bottom margin. If it's a landscape image it should be as large as it can be before hits the left/right margin.

At the moment I'm dragging each file across and resizing them manually. Is it possible just drop them on the page and get them auto resized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the A4 image frame at the master layout, drag the image at the page, then:

**Menu Object** > **Fitting** > **Fit Content Proportionally**

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>E</kbd> Mac

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>E</kbd> Win

Or

**Menu Object** > **Fitting** > **Fit Frame Proportionally**

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd> Mac

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd> Win

Comment: is there a way to set the default fitting option for a document. Also if i create an image frame in the master page, then on a slave page when i input and then delete an image it removes the frame, why is this ? I thought items taken from a master page could not be effected on subsequent slave pages